# How to connect to run an ansible task inside a docker container on a remote host (via ssh)

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to use ansible tasks to make changes to a postgres database (ex, add user) running **inside a docker container** on a **remote host** which is only accessible via **ssh**.

I was only ably to make either a local docker connection or remote docker connection with exposed docker port. Which is no an option.

Is this possible at all? Should i use a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to get Ansible by itself to run tasks *inside* a container on a remote host. There are a few workarounds you could try:

### Docker socket forwarding

Rather than exposting the Docker socket publically, forward it over your ssh connection. E.g:

```
ssh -L /tmp/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock remotehost
```

While this connection is active, you can access the remote docker over the local socket `/tmp/docker.sock`, e.g. by setting `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///tmp/docker.sock` in your environment.

This means you can use Ansible's `docker` connection driver to run tasks inside the remote container.

### Just run the commands on the remote host

If you've got Postgres running inside a container on the remote host, you don't need to run tasks inside the container in order to talk to Postgres. With appropriate authentication, you can connect directly to postgres on the container's ip address, or to a port published on the host.

In either case, you would use Ansible's normal `ssh` connection driver.

Comment: Tried packaging the Docker socket forwarding solution as a role, but it didn't work reliably for me. Sometimes raw commands like "echo" just fail, sometimes they work fine and I don't understand why
https://github.com/v4dkou/ansible-remote-docker